# How to handle the json object sent as parameter in post request using $.ajax(); and rest webservices

Tags: java, ajax, json, resteasy, http-post

I am sending a json object in post request using jquery ajax as below.

```
$.ajax({
   url:'example/test/do',
   type:'POST',
   cache: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    data : [{id:'22',name:'hari'},{id:'32',name:'sharat'}],
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

And i have a bean as below

```
class User{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}
class UserList{
    private List<User>  userList;
    //getter setter comes here
}
```

And the method to handle request

```
@POST
@PATH('/test/do')
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response acceptUsers(@Form UserList list){
    System.out.println(list.getUserList().size()); // i am getting zero    
  //actual code comes here
}
```

I am sorry i am getting list as null and when i use size it obviously throws NullPointerException.

How to receive the sent information of users into list of User objects, basically mapping/converting the json object to List of Pojo.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually sending JSON, it should be

```
data : JSON.stringify([{id:'22',name:'hari'},{id:'32',name:'sharat'}]),
```

Comment: It is a json object already and i tried using JSON.Stringify() same problem.

Comment: You're passing a **JavaScript Array Literal** (which is not JSON) to jQuery ajax, which will most likely be converted to `[object Object],[object Object]` and sent in the request body. `JSON.stringify()`(notice the common s) will convert the array to JSON. I don't know resteasy  but I'd try using an array of `User` rather than a `UserList` for the `acceptUsers` parameter list.